# Hibernate migration 6.1 to 6.2 - @OneToOne with @JoinColumn - ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement - Duplicate entry '1' for key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have simple Relation User to Role

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;



@Entity(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

after update of Hibernate from **6.1.7** to **6.2.2** I get following Error

```
15:51:37.348 [main] [ traceId:   spanId:   ]  INFO  [ork.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryEnhancerFactory:47.<clinit>()] - Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used. 
15:51:39.427 [main] [ traceId:   spanId:   ]  WARN  [  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:145.logExceptions()] - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000 
15:51:39.427 [main] [ traceId:   spanId:   ]  ERROR [  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:150.logExceptions()] - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user.UK_qleu8ddawkdltal07p8e6hgva' 
15:51:39.440 [main] [ traceId:   spanId:   ]  ERROR [             io.config.db.DataInitializer:213.init()] - Cannot initialize internal users. 
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user.UK_qleu8ddawkdltal07p8e6hgva'] [insert into user (account_id,created,last_login,last_modified,locked,recover_verify_token,recover_verify_token_exp,role_id,status,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into user (account_id,created,last_login,last_modified,role_id,status,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; constraint [user.UK_qleu8ddawkdltal07p8e6hgva]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:269)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:565)
....
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user.UK_qleu8ddawkdltal07p8e6hgva'] [insert into user (account_id,created,last_login,last_modified,role_id,status,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]
```

In [Migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.2/migration/html_single/#_introduction) I do not find some relevant information.

With version **6.1.7** is everything fine and mapping is working as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not facing any issue with 6.2.x to save duplicate data. Please drop the table and let the hibernate create and then persist the data. See if that works.

Comment: Can you provide your code base to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm dropping whole schema and creating and initialize it from the scratch. Unfortunately can't, it is too big.

Comment: ok. Is there any way to reproduce this? I'm unable to reproduce on my local.

Comment: I think there is not a problem at framework version but in usage of it and the real reason can be that you are using `@OneToOne` relation as `@OneToMany`. And also a question about relations(not relevant to your question) can one user have multiple roles ?

Comment: Can you update the question with an example(real values) ?, where you are doing insert into database first row and at second you have this exception(also add insert statements)

Comment: Can I do, But this constellation is working for two years without any problems in different Hibernate versions. The problem is only with this version Yes @OneToOne is correct. 1 user can have one Role. Ok. I'm using spring. With Spring 3.0.9 is working, with 3.1.0 not. In Spring 3.0.9 - Hibernate 6.1.7. In Spring 3.1.0 i Hibernate 6.2.2

Comment: It happens, if I add second user with the same role.

Comment: Can you tell me how you solved this problem? I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't solve this problem. I still have Hibernate 6.1.7. But I also have an update coming soon.. ((

Comment: Having same issue, while updated project to Hibernate 6.2. I have to change relation type.
See https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/onetoone-mapping-has-unique-constraint-when-generating-schema/7642

Comment: @JDev - it did. Hibernate is not generating unique constraint with ManyToOne. Error is gone for me.

Comment: @PavelMuravyov can you please share the solution? "Was => should be". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the migration doc: [link](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.2/migration-guide.adoc#logical-1-1-unique), you should change relation type in User entity from @OneToOne to @ManyToOne (and not adding @UniqueConstraint, unless you need it)

Before:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
```

After:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I think I missed something or don't understand. But this is a completely different type of relationship. How will it work? In my case, the user has one role.

Comment: As I understand correctly from what Hibernate team suggests is that canonical OneToOne should mean exactly one record per table. Like for example user and its user_data (to one user we can assign only one unique data record). All other cases are somewhat different.
In our case user table can contain same role relation multiple times.

Strange is that it become that strict only in version 6.2 and later.

Comment: What about relationship then? Why have it if you can't use it?
This is exactly how OneToOne  is working. Creates 1 record in the table.
It turns out that now I need to replace all OneToOne records with ManyToOne?

Kind of stupid...